# Row By Row Compare Value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, compare, row

I'm a novice in Excel VBA.
Currently, I have imported a bunch of data into Excel, the data is in this form:

```
     A     B
11  397  -57.6
12  397  -57.3
13  270  -55
```

---

Is it possible to compare the value of current row and the next row? If there is same value occurred in column A, compare column B and the row with larger value in column B will be selected and another row will be deleted. Example: row A11: 397 B11:-57.6 will be deleted.

```
Sub RadiatedEmission()
    iPath = "C:\Users\Raw Datas\Radiated Emission\110V\06863-EMC-00014\Report\"
    iFile = Dir(iPath & "*.dat")

    Do While Len(iFile)
        Sheets.Add , Sheets(Sheets.Count), , iPath & iFile
        iFile = Dir

        Columns.AutoFit

       'start from row 11, if column A have the same value, compare column 
       B, take max(larger value), arrage in ascending order

    Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done by sorting the table appropriately (Sort by A, then by B). Then you can use the Remove Duplicates tool (Data -> Data Tools -> Remove Duplicates) to remove the lines with duplicated A values leaving only the first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I think of this method too but this unable to work in my situation. Because there is 2 section, and the row of data is a variable for every file, if I use the method that u have mentioned, it will mix up the data from the two section....So I think that it is better to compare the value line by line but I have no idea how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work but you will want to tidy it up as I made it quite awkward to make it more readable.

```
Sub compareLines()

Dim currentRow, nextRow As Integer

currentRow = 11
nextRow = 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

    If ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value - ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 1).Value < 
0 Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(nextRow, 0).Select
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kieran! Thanks for the code! As I mentioned, I have 2 sections of data. [Section 1 Title] First set of data and continue by [Section 2 Title] Second set of data. The data format is as stated in my question. The code works! But only for first section of data.
Anything to add so that it can continue to compare the second set of data? Your help to appreciated!

Comment: @Irene94 I dont understand where this second set of data is?

Answer (score 0):

This code will delete duplicate rows with lower values.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = LastRow To 11 Step -1 'change 11 to the top row
        If Cells(i, "B").Value <> Application.Evaluate("MAX(IF(" & Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(LastRow, "A")).Address _
            & "=" & Cells(i, "A").Address & "," & Range(Cells(1, "B"), Cells(LastRow, "B")).Address & "))") Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Let me know if anything is not clear. Got this from [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/463610-delete-duplicate-row-but-keep-one-highest-number-cell-next.html).

Comment: Hi Mrig! Thanks for the code! The codes compared the value for the first group of data but it deleted all the second group's data...and also the titles for both set of data...

Comment: @Irene94 - What exactly do mean? Are you saying code is deleting data in 'Column B' ? Well I'm deleting the complete row so removing column value seems unlikely. Also for deletion, loop is iterated till 'Row 11' thus anything above row 11 will not be deleted. Can you post a screen shot of what result you getting.

Comment: Erm...Let me think how to explain it...My have 2 sections of data.  [Section 1 Title] First set of data and continue by [Section 2 Title] Second set of data. It only compare the data in first section and deleted the title of both section and also the data in second section. By the way, I found the code I need from https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1014237-compare-value-current-row-next-row.html. Thanks for  your patient and also effort, I appreciate it!